# Add event to submit button fail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i dont understand what's wrong when i try to add event listener to submit button. I load the form from the page "formLogin.php", maybe the problem is that, i cant add event from a form of another page.

20.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES"><html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="21-12-16.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

        <script src="20.js"></script>

        <title>Menu</title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="header">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">LOGIN</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="" id="conect">Conect</a>
                            <ul>
                                <!--<li><a href="">Sub menu</a></li>-->
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     <div id="response-container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

20.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    function Login() {
       this.loadForm = function() {

          $("#response-container").load("formLogin.php");

          $( "#formLogin" ).submit(function( event ) {    //THIS CODE NOT WORKS
              alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
              event.preventDefault();
          });     
       };

       this.searchData = function() {    
          getdetails( "1" )
          .done( function( response ) {
                if( response.success ) {
                       alert("Success");
                } else {
                }
          })
          .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                $("#response-container").html("fail");
          });
       };

       var getdetails = function(id){
          return $.getJSON( "20.php", { "id" : id });
       }
    };

    //LISTENERS
    $('#conect').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var login= new Login();
        login.loadForm();
    });        
});
```

formLogin.php

```
<form id="formLogin" method="get" action="20.html">
USERNAME:<br><input type="text" name="username" /><br>
PASSWORD:<br><input type="password" name="password" /><br>

<br><input type="submit" value="Log in" name="login" id="btnInputLogin"/>
</form>
```

Comment: how is `formLogin.php` connected?

Comment: @Jeff Sorry if i dont understand your question, im not in local server, im using a hosting, the form load perfectly, but the event is not added to the form.

Comment: You have 3 files, 2 of them are connected, because you include the js into the html. `formLogin.php` is not connected to the others (at least we don't see it). The js-file has to be included/connected to formLogin.php to work

Comment: hangon, I found your problem.... the `load` is the "problem". It's asynch of course, so the creating of the event-handles have to be inside the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that `load()` is asynchronous. That meens, that any action based on the result has to be inside it's callback function:

```
                                              // here's the difference
      $("#response-container").load("formLogin.php", function() {

         $( "#formLogin" ).submit(function( event ) {    //THIS CODE SHOULD NOW WORK
              alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
              event.preventDefault();
         }); 
      });
```

*Short explanation:*
You've set an eventlistened at a time, where the element (#formLogin) was not yet in the DOM, it still was loading. That's what callback functions are for. They get triggered once the action is done.

Here's the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: thank you very match bro, you save my life, im a silly noob. I appreciatte so much your help. I need to learn more about callback functions then, because al the time im working with them, i dont know if that is a good practice or bad.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it is good practice! And if my answer helped you can accept it!